# Where can I place my code for initialization, in MVC 5?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session, asp.net-mvc-5

In MVC 5 I have an action `CheckDbVersion()`. I only want to make this check one time. At the moment I call it from my _Layout with some AJAX.

How can I change it so I only call it one time (in _Layout, I call View's that re-render the _Layout)? Should I make the call some other place or create some sort of "Initialization is done" in a Session or Cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it be called one time total, or one time for each person?

If you want it to be called once ever, you could put it in the `Global.asax.cs` `Application_Start()`. This will be called the first time the application starts, instead of being triggered by users coming to the page.

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        //etc
        CheckDbVersion();
    }
```

Comment: It's a partial good solution. It does the job, and only once like I need. Do you know about the HandleError attribute? I use it to show differens error pages. My problem is that it doesn't seems like `HandleError` works on `Application_Start()`, so I'm stuck with YSOD. Do you know a solution to this? It would be much appriciated and really help me alot thanks.

Comment: please expand upon your question if this is relevant to this specific question, or ask a new question if it's unrelated. I do not understand what you're looking for from your comment.

Comment: Yeah you're right you answered the question. I thought (maybe hoped the two things was close related. I'm just wondering how to handle an error in `Application_start()` and show a nice error message to the User. Loging is easy, but I also need to not into Yellow Screen Of Death. But thanks anyway, I will ask another question.

Comment: `Application_Start()` is only called once ever, so it wouldn't make sense to try to handle application errors there. There is an `Application_Error()` in the global.asax though